# Replacing Indirect with Choose in Named Range Reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I made a named range that uses indirect to return a table with about 43K objects in it. Im beginning to understand that it is taxing Excel incredibly since I use the data from the table in many calculations on my worksheet. How would I implement the `Choose` function into this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"$A$1:$M"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"A:A")))
```

I'm trying to see if this will help my file not use 18 GB to calculate my workbook whenever I run a macro where that indirect named range changes constantly.

Comment: how many different option can `'Loss Template'!$S$33` be?  CHOOSE will require that you put each option as a full reference.  This could get quite large if there are too many.

Comment: 13 options. I dont mind writing one big choose formula to make the named range if that helps make it not volatile.

Comment: It would be better to write a Worksheet_Change event that updates the formulas when ever the value changes.

Comment: well the thing is the raw data changes with each option. what if i made the each option a table instead of its own worksheet. Would that make it less taxing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? I can provide additional context if you need that to help.

Answer (score 0):

I made a choose formula after researching and it seems to make a difference.

`=CHOOSE($S$47,Jun_19,Jul_19,Aug_19,Sep_19,Oct_19,Nov_19,Dec_19,Jan_20,Feb_20,Mar_20,Apr_20,May_20,Jun_20)`